# Find roots in cubic equation $x^3+(1-2a)x^2-(3a^2+a+2)x-6a^2+6a=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

In the equation

$$x^3+(1-2a)x^2-(3a^2+a+2)x-6a^2+6a=0$$

How should I go to find the roots of $~x~$? Is it possible to apply the factor theorem somehow?

Comment: [Cardano's Formulas](https://www.mathemania.com/lesson/cardanos-formula-solving-cubic-equations/) are always a backup plan for cubics and quartics. Here, though, Vieta's formulas are more useful. If $q, r, s$ are your roots, you have $$qrs = 2a-1$$$$qr+rs+sq=-(3a^2+a+2)$$$$q+r+s=6a(a-1)$$

Comment: You might try the rational root theorem; roots that are rational in $a$ should be factors of $6a-6a^2$ if you are considering general $a$.

Comment: @DonThousand I think you've switched the left-hand sides of the first and third equations.

Comment: By inspection, the equation as a integer solution. Then long division to reduce to a quadratic.

Comment: @Travis Yea I did, I was copy pasting without checking properly. Good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** We can think of the polynomial as a quadratic polynomial equation in $a$ with parameter $x$:

$$(-3x - 6) a^2 + (-2 x^2 - x + 6) a + (x^3 + x^2 - 2 x) = 0. $$
Factoring coefficients gives
$$0 = -3(x + 2) a^2 - (x + 2) (2 x - 3) a + (x + 2) x (x - 1) .$$

> **Additional hint** Factoring the entire expression gives: $$0 = -(x + 2) [3 a^2 + (2 x - 3) a - x (x - 1)] ,$$ so (1) $x = -2$ is a solution, and (2) to find the other solutions we need only factor the quadratic $3 a^2 + (2 x - 3) a - x (x - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, in the cubic equation, the constant term is $a$-dependent and the terms free of $a$ form the equation below,

$$x^3+x^2-2x=x(x-1)(x+2)=0$$

which admits the roots $0$, $1$ and $-2$. Plug them into the full equation

$$x^3+(1-2a)x^2-(3a^2+a+2)x-6a^2+6a=0$$
to identify that $x=-2$ is an actual root and $x+2$ is a factor. Thus, the equation can be factorized as

$$(x+2)(x-3a)(x+a-1)=0$$

Then, the three roots are $-2$, $3a$ and $1-a$.

Comment: Neat! $\qquad{{{{{}}}}}$